# Mapbox camera goes to totally different location

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

I am using mapbox in Android with kotlin.
I want to set the map camera location but when i set it, it goes to a totally different place.
I tested in debugging mode and the coordinates are correct.
For example I am in Portugal and it goes to Madagascar.

```
map.flyTo( cameraOptions {

    center( Point.fromLngLat( location.latitude, location.longitude) )
},
MapAnimationOptions.mapAnimationOptions {
    duration(7000)
})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is LngLat and your parameters are latitude, longitude.

From [MapBox:](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/geography/)

> "These coordinates use longitude, latitude coordinate order (as
> opposed to latitude, longitude) to match the GeoJSON specification,
> which is equivalent to the OGC:CRS84 coordinate reference system."

So try:

```
center( Point.fromLngLat( location.longitude, location.latitude) )
```

Comment: I am so embarrassed right now XD. I switched and it worked perfectly. Thank You